# eslint standard for react-native

Tags: react-native, eslint

I am new to react-native and I am looking for a standard solution for react-native, does anyone have any ideas for this. In react I install `npm i standard -D` and add a configuration in the `package.json` file and when I open my components the errors are highlighted.